# How to declare a variable and its type is Boolean in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, boolean

When I study PowerShell scripting language, I knew the data type is auto-assignment. If I want to declare a Boolean type variable, how can I do it?

Example: $myvariable = "string" or $myvalue = 3.14159
$myboolean ?

Comment: are you looking for `= $true`?

Comment: I understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Boolean values (which can be either 1 or 0) are defined in PowerShell using the .Net System.Boolean type (the short from of which is [bool]). For example, the following command assigns true to a variable of boolean type:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [bool] $myval = 1
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $myval.gettype().fullname
System.Boolean
```

When working with boolean variables, the pre-defined

$true

and

> $false

variables may also be used:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [bool] $myval = $false
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $myval
False
```